# Encrypted vs decrypted field

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am storing database credentials and I have data like this:

```
id = 1
port = 3306
type = "MySQL"
user = "hellobob"
password = "asdofiasndofi34343"
```

For the fields user or password, what would be a good way to tell if that data is in an ecrypted or unencrypted state? For example, the password may be something like:

```
"aosdifhoasidjf234234"
```

When it is unencrypted, but like:

```
"239489283749234li"
```

when it is encrypted. How could I tell the difference? My thought was to add a prefix to it. Something like:

```
"asdoifjaosdifjasdfioj" <== unencrypted
"X-asdofijasodifjo34i5j345" <== encrypted
```

Is the above a good solution, or are there better ways of doing this? Also, what would be a good way to encrypt/decrypt the data for these fields?

Comment: You should **never** save encrypted passwords in your database. Only hashed ones, and better salt them with random before you do so.

Comment: @Dekel -- sure, so how would I do that and tell the difference between whether it's hashed/salted or whether it's not?

Comment: You don't need to determine this. You put only hashed passwords in the database - thus you know that everything inside is hashed. What is the question?

Comment: you have the right idea with the prefix ... look at how django stores their passwords `$<method>$<salt>$<hashed-password>` so something like `$sha1$123AAx$asdw4324f2rf324525345` this allows me to listen for the save event ... if the password does not start with `$sha1` it is not hashed, and i must hash it

Comment: @Dekel -- if I don't know the actual password I cannot connect to the database. I need the credentials to connect to the database.

Comment: Maybe I misread the question - if you are talking about the password to connect to the database - they should not be hashed/encrypted (since you use that password in order to connect). If you are talking about passwords of users/members/something else that you save in your database - everything I wrote above is relevant.

Comment: the reason he says not to encrypt them is that encryption is reversable giving you the actual password the user used... hashes are one way "encryption" ie you cannot in a general sense take a hash and determine what password a user used

Comment: @JoranBeasley right -- what I'm asking here is how I can have a reversible encrypt/decypt. Much like any 'locker' or 'keypass' would have -- where a user has their user/password stored -- the user needs to be able to view them when the login to it.